# A question about Parameter passing in c#

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

The below example is got from Jon Skeet's article, "[Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)".

My question is: Why variable y is **NOT** null in the first example while we see that it has been changed in the second example:

1-

```
void Foo (StringBuilder x)
{
    x = null;
}

...

StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
y.Append ("hello");
Foo (y);
Console.WriteLine (y==null);
```

2-

```
void Foo (StringBuilder x)
{
    x.Append (" world");
}

...

StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
y.Append ("hello");
Foo (y);
Console.WriteLine (y);
```

Thank you

Comment: I tested the 1) example and it prints `False`. Why do you say it's null?

Comment: the first example should not result in y being null... if that is what you want you need to pass the parameter x as ref (*void Foo (ref StringBuilder x*) to be able to modify what the original variable is pointing to.

Comment: If (1) would print out true I would be truly surprised. As stated below, within Foo x is a local variable referencing the same object as y. The contents of why can be change by using x.something, but you can not change where y acutally points to. For this to work, you would need to pass x by reference

Comment: @outis: Thank you for linking Jon Skeet' article

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`y` is *not* null in the first example, precisely because the argument is passed by value. The argument expression (simply `y`) is evaluated, and its value (a reference to a `StringBuilder` is copied into the parameter variable (`x`) as the initial value.

Changing the value of `x` does *not* change the value of `y`.

The second example doesn't change the value of the parameter (`x`) - it changes the data within the object that `x` refers to. The value of `y` still hasn't changed: it still refers to the same `StringBuilder` object, it's just that that object now contains different data.

If I give you a piece of paper with my home address on, and you go to that address and paint the house red, you're not changing anything about the piece of paper, are you? And if you *did* cross out my address on the piece of paper (as in the first example) that wouldn't change *my* idea of my address - just as changing the value of `x` doesn't change the value of `y`.

Comment: Jon, What about the socond example? "y" has been sent to "Foo" by value again, but we see the result as "helloworld" it means that Foo has changed y.

Comment: @odiseh: No, the value of `y` hasn't changed. It refers to the same `StringBuilder` as it did before - it's just that the *contents* of the `StringBuilder` have changed. That's the equivalent of going to my house and painting it red - you're not changing where I live, just what the house there looks like.

Comment: @Skeet - what if you gave your address as "the blue house"? :)

Comment: heh, funny how "pieces of paper" seems to be an universal way of explaining pointers :)

Comment: @Pauli: The "piece of paper" combined with "painting a house" is a way of explaining it that seems to be useful. I should really update my parameter passing page to give it as an example some time... it seems to have helped a number of people. My only reservation about it is that people may then equate "reference" with "memory address" which isn't necessarily accurate. A reference it just a way of identifying an object, and may not be a simple pointer.

Answer (score 3):

In both examples the reference to the StringBuilder is being passed by value.
Think of `y` as the holder of the address of the actual StringBuilder.
The address itself is being copied to Foo's as stack parameter so the assignment `x = null` in the first example changes the copied address and not the actual address stored in `y`.
On the second example `x.Append` refers to the same instance that y points to and changes it, hence the change is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, that makes more sense... it is because how pointer work. In both examples you are passing a copy of a pointer to the function. Imagine `y` being a piece of paper saying "second door on the left", this is the room where we want to store the string.

Now, in the first example you're making a copy of that piece of paper and the method is taking that copy and erasing what it says. Since its just a copy of the paper the original piece is not affected.

So now, when we're back and we want to print the content of y, we follow the instructions, find the "second door on the left", open it and finds only "hello"

In the second example, we're still passing a copy of the paper, but now we need to interact so we follow the instructions to get to the "second door on the left" and in here we append the string " world". So now, when we're back and we want to print the content of y, we follow the instructions written on our original piece of paper, find the "second door on the left", open it and finds "hello world".

If we had used the `ref`-keyword, we wouldn't have passed a copy of the paper, but the actual paper itself to the method. So when the method erases what is written on the paper, we are now back with no directions to find the door where our string is stored.

I know, its a bit childish explanation but it usually works when trying to explain pointers.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by Itay *"the reference to the StringBuilder is being passed by value"*.

When you call `Foo(y)` it copies the value of `y` which is the address of the memory where the data(value) is located so in both cases in `x` you have the copy of the address to where `y` variable is pointing. Note that `x` is not referencing `y` it just gets the copy of the `y` reference type variable value. So by assigning null to `x` you ***just cut the reference*** from x to some address (which in out case stores text, StringBuilder data). And as `x` just gets copy of the `y` variable and not referencing it `y` is not changed. 
In the second example you are just manipulating data in address to which `y` is referencing that is why after method call `y` is updated.

Let me add comments on both cases

1-

```
void Foo (StringBuilder x) // x gets copy of the address to where y is referencing 
{
    // x now points to null 
    // Remember x and y variables are located in different memory addresses and x is 
    // not referencing y, thus only x is updated.
    x = null;
}
...
```

2-

```
void Foo (StringBuilder x) // x gets copy of the address to where y is referencing 
{
    // x updates the data located in the memory address to which y is referencing
    // x still points to the same address as y 
    x.Append (" world");
}
...
```

Try this, it will clear up much:

```
void Foo (ref StringBuilder x) // x points to y
{
    x = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: When I answered the question, it stated that Y was null. The question has since been changed.

I think you've written the code wrong. I've updated your code - note that the Foo argument is now passed by "reference" and not by "value".

```
class Program
{
    static void Foo(ref StringBuilder x)
    {
        x = null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
        y.Append("hello");
        Foo(ref y);
        Console.WriteLine(y == null); //Prints "true".
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For (1) to print out true, the code would have to look like this:

```
void Foo (ref StringBuilder x)
{
    x = null;
}

...

StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
y.Append ("hello");
Foo (ref y);
Console.WriteLine (y==null);
```

Mario

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you're familiar with pointers, but it'll help you understand this better.  Because parameters represent pointers to objects, if you assign the pointer to another object, you're changing where the pointer points to therefore you're not modifying the original object.

In the second example, you're calling a method of the object of the original pointer, therefore the original object gets modified.

Java did it this way on purpose so that there would be no ambiguity as to how assigning variables works.  If you want to assign a variable to an object defined in a method, you must return that object to be assigned to the variable (`StringBuilder builder = createStringBuilder();` for instance)

Comment: -1 misleading; In a function call the reference is a local variable. unless it is passed by reference you can not change to where the variable points for the outside world.

Comment: A pointer parameter is a local variable technically.  And yes, you can assign it to anything you want and it would reference it just like you can assign an integer to any number you like.  Point is that you'd lose the original worth of the parameter just like if you had reassigned an integer parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Becuase in the first example he passes Y to Foo which sets Y to null:

```
Foo (y);
....


void Foo (StringBuilder x) 
{     
     x = null; 
}
```

Comment: No, it changes only the local reference `x`. `y` is not changed.

Comment: -1 x is a local variable within Foo. It is not passed by ref. Whatever is assigned to x within the function does not change where to te passed variable points outside the function.

Answer (score -4):

So I figured I'll correct my answer so no one read the old one since it was wrong. I was a little bit confused by the question. So the answer is:

When you are passing in an object reference to a method you have access to that objects properties and methods. But if you change your input parameter to something else the object want be changed since your are changing what the variable is referencing to. Hopefully this example explains it better, otherwise read Jon Skeet's answer.

```
public static void DoSomething(MyObject x)
{
    x.MyProperty = 2;
    x = new MyObject(); // now we lost our reference to original object
    x.MyProperty = 3; // The original object is NOT updated.
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var y = MyObject();
    y.MyProperty = 1;
    DoSomething(y);
    Console.WriteLine(y.MyProperty); // Will output "2"
}
```

Comment: I think you're confused because the question is confused - `y` *isn't* actually `null` in the first example. Passing a reference (by value) *doesn't* give the method control over the argument. I also think you meant "immutable" when you referred to string - but regardless of that, mutability of a type doesn't change how arguments are passed. (It can't: neither the CLR nor the compiler has any concept of a type being immutable.)

Comment: That isn't accurate.  The references gives the method access to the same object yes, but if the method decided to null the reference it was given or place a new object inside, this will NOT mutate the caller.  If the parameter was a ref parameter however, it would.

Comment: See my comment to Mark Robinson's answer.

Comment: -1 In a function call the reference is a local variable. unless it is passed by reference you can not change to where the variable points for the outside world.